# Query with sum many columns from same table with laravel query

Tags: laravel

This seems very easy query but can't translate it into laravel query. I have table `orders` there are two columns `total_usd` and `total_gbp`. I want to sum each column to get total of usd and total of gbp on the page.

This query is working in phpmyadmin and I got correct result

```
SELECT sum(order_total_usd) as usd, sum(order_total_gbp) as gbp FROM `orders`
```

In laravel I've tried this

```
$sumOrders = Order::select('sum(order_total_gbp) as gbp, sum(order_total_usd) as usd');
```

when I `dd($sumOrders)` I've one really huge output which almost cause browser to freeze. 
Where is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$sumOrders = Order::select( \DB::raw("sum(order_total_gbp) as gbp"),  \DB::raw("sum(order_total_usd) as usd"))->get();
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Now when I `dd($sumOrders['gbp'])` in order to access the sum of `gdp` I've got `Undefined index: gdp`.

Comment: You have to get like `$sumOrders->gdp`

Comment: When I `dd($sumOrders->gbp)` I've got `ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$gbp`. When I `dd($sumOrders)` I've got one relatively long array and inside I can see `array(2) { ["gbp"]=> float(0.43829558) ["usd"]=> float(27) }`

Comment: Okay got it to work. I've changed `->get()` with `->first()` at the end and now is working. Thanks

Comment: @Ivan Glad I could help! :) –

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectRaw

```
$sumOrders = Order::selectRaw('sum(order_total_gbp) as gbp, sum(order_total_usd) as usd');
```

Comment: Thanks but this return again `ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$gbp`

Answer (score 0):

Except for one missed word, your code is OK. Add "Raw" after "select" as shown:

```
$sumOrders = 
Order::selectRaw(
    'sum(order_total_gbp) as gbp, 
    sum(order_total_usd) as usd'
);
```

Just replace "Order::select(...)" with Order::select**Raw**(...).

Have a great day!